# Multiplayer turn based Android/iOS

Tags: unity, multiplayer, mobile, turn-based, turn-based-strategy

We're developing a mobile endless runner game, on Unity3d where you can challenge your Facebook friends. The only interaction between the players is the challenge - one player challenges the other, then each player plays when he wants, and after both players finish (when their character dies), their scores are compared to determine the winner.
What system would you recommend that would allow us to implement this functionality, considering scalability, cost and ease of use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't give technology recommendations, because they are too opinion-based.

Comment: I was about to post an answer. Anyway... Take a look at this: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/TBMP.md#google-play-games-plugin-for-unity-turn-based-multiplayer

Comment: Thanks! Does this work only for Google Play users? Or can I use Facebook users?

Comment: @DiegoGonzález This IS, actually, only made for Google Play users.

Comment: Do you know anything that works with Facebook?